# Copy / pasting specific cells from a given row Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on summary reporting page that is used to report certain data on a log of quality issues for the company i work for.

To give you a run down of how its supposed to work.
The code is supposed to take the current weeknum, minus 1 to this valve and then search through a log of data. I'm getting it to search the data using a For loop like so. Column "H" contain a week number and we are searching for the current week number minus 1

```
 For i = 8 To DataLastRow
        If datasheet.Range("H" & i).Value = currentweeknum - 1 And datasheet.Range("C" & i).Value = projectNum Then
```

This weeks really well, and when i find a given row with the correct value in column "H", i can copy the entire row using the following code:

```
datasheet.range(i).copy
```

I can also paste this row onto a separate sheet (my summary sheet) using this:

```
LastRowRpt = summarysheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
summarysheet.Range("A" & LastRowRpt + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Again, this works well, however its got to the point now where i do not want to copy the entire row. I need to copy only specific columns in that row as not all the data is needed for the summary.

I did find a way to get this done, however its slowing down Excel, and i've not finished writing the code yet. My current way is to copy the required cell in the row, then paste it into the desired location on the summary sheet, before moving on to copying the next cell and pasting that. There is an exactly of 2 below, but there is a lot more in my code.

```
'topic
datasheet.Range("E" & i).Copy
summarysheet.Range("C" & summarysheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Owner
datasheet.Range("F" & i).Copy
summarysheet.Range("D" & summarysheet.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

As i mentioned, this is really slowing down excel and i have to create another summary sheet for different data but essentially does the same thing.

Is there a way i can condense my code, and make the operation a lot more efficient so excel doesn't slow down too much?
Its worth noting that i want the valves only pasting, so using Destination:= is not useful as the entire format is copied over - something which i do not want.

Comment: Using `range("a1").value=range("b1").value` is quicker than using the copy/paste.

Comment: Also doesn't look like you have to do each cell individually.

Comment: Try using arrays. Anyhow, consecutively copying to adiacent cells (E:F) in C:D, should be done at once `using the ranges value. If you post a piece of code to see the logic, I can help with an arrays variant. Working only in memory it would be very fast. If you prefer to show you something starting from what you presented, I can do it, but I am not sure you will understand it as it very well... At least, which columns do you try processing?

Comment: Is that "log of data" a text file, or another Excel Workshet?